# MySQL InnoDB - Can you set a FK on a column that is part of PK?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, composite-primary-key

Can a foreign key be set on a column that is also part of the primary key?

Table has 3 fields: userId, followId, followDate
Current PK on the combo of userId and followId
Trying to add userId as a FK to users table as well as followId to users table

I keep getting "ERROR 1005: Can't create table '.\database#sql-634_cc.frm' (errno: 121)".

ADD CONSTRAINT `userId`
  FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Or is there a different error I'm not seeing?

Comment: Can you include the complete DDL statements to set up the tables?

Comment: Show us the value that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes, this is possible. The problem was FK's in a DB need to have unique names. I had 'userId' as an FK on another table, so I prefixed the name of the FK on this table to 'table_userId'

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. As this is the common behavior.